# How to download an .exe file successfully in C#?

Tags: c#, download, async-await, webclient, downloadfileasync

I am trying to download a `test.exe` file with this code:

```
public void DownloadFile()
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
         client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://www.acromix.net16.net/download/test.exe"), "test.exe");
    }
}
```

With this simple code, I debug it and this was the output:
[image: output]

I don't know and have no idea why it is 0 KB (should be 328 KB).
[[/downloads](http://www.acromix.net16.net/download)]

How can I make it work?

**EDIT:**
 The hosting site (000webhost) blocks `.exe` files to download...

Comment: Why are you using the `Async` version?

Comment: Check out this article at Microsoft. It is a asynchronous downloading program written in C# that will help you.


https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Asynchronous-Downloader-61955c78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers...

Anyway, I found out that I can't really download an `.exe` file from where I hosted my website ([000webhost](http://000webhost.com)) because it is blocked (for safety reasons I think).

A workaround, first, I need to put an `.exe` file to a zip folder then upload it so I would be able to download it successfully...

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that you are using `DownloadFileAsync` which is an async version. To know when download is complete you have to subscribe to `DownloadFileCompleted` event.

Either use sync method:

```
public void DownloadFile()
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://www.acromix.net16.net/download/test.exe"), "test.exe");
    }
}
```

Or use new async-await approach:

```
public async Task DownloadFileAsync()
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(new Uri("http://www.acromix.net16.net/download/test.exe"), "test.exe");
    }
}
```

Then call this method like this:

```
await DownloadFileAsync();
```

Comment: Because, with the `WebClient` that would be `DownloadFileTaskAsync`.

Comment: @PauloMorgado, thanks. `DownloadFileAsync` is void. correct one is `DownloadFileTaskAsync`.

Answer (score 1):

[WebClient.DownloadFileAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfileasync?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP8656) uses an [Event-based Asynchronous Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/wewwczdw?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP8656) and, as any **XXXAsync** [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP8656) that predates `async`-`await`, requires subscribing to a ***XXXCompleted*** event. So, in the case of **DownloadFile** the [DownloadFileCompleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP8656) should be subscribed to wait for the completion of the download.

With the advent of `async`-`await` comes the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh873175?Wt.mc_id=DX_MVP8656). Usually, TAP methods are suffixed **Async**, but since there were already **Async** sufixed members in the class, the second rules applies and the methods are suffixed **TaskAsync**.

Since the OP tagged the question with `async`-`await`, the correct code would be:

```
public async Task DownloadFileAsync()
{
    using(var client = new WebClient())
    {
         await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(
            new Uri("http://www.acromix.net16.net/download/test.exe"),
            "test.exe");
    }
}
```